# Manga where MC and his sister are transported to another world. Has a harem and is a very strong adventurer. Can't lose his virginity

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character has a Yandere sister who also gets transported to the same world as him and becomes very strong. He tries to lose his virginity but every time gets interrupted by someone. He has a harem and is a very strong adventurer.

Comment: I fixed your tags, and moved some details from the title into the body. Did you read this in print? Online? When? How many chapters? How was the translation quality? Color or black and white? Is he aware of his in-game stats? Does he have a Perk or Gift or something like that that makes him special? Is He strong physically? Magically? Psychic? Lucky? What kind of women are in his harem? Are they all human?

Comment: Is that sister a murderous sociopath that literally tortures and mutilates other girls that get close to her brother, even before going to the other world?

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-shihai-no-skill-taker-zero-kara-hajimeru-dorei-harem/reviews?

Comment: @qazmlpok Yes,You are right

Answer (score 2):

This is likely *[Tensei Gotoki de Nigerareru to demo, Nii-san?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tensei-gotoki-de-nigerareru-to-demo-nii-san)*.

> The older brother, imprisoned by his sister, dies just as he escapes and is reincarnated in another world! He thought he had been freed from his demonic sister, but now she too has been reincarnated in the same world...?

The main character's sister is an obsessive stalker that kidnaps and mutilates any women that get close to him, seeking to keep him for herself. Both of them die and are reborn in the same world, where she discovers him again.

Comment: Normally I'd include images and read more of the series to ensure it's a proper match, but this honestly isn't something I want to go back to.